# Tabset, event triggers way too often

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, cropperjs

An event will be fired([console](https://ibb.co/MNXxvW2)) a 'million' time, when you just start moving your mouse, this will slow down the dialog(when you have more than one item).

I prepared an example:
[Stacklitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sgeznz)

What can I do ?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: You need to share the editor url

Comment: @AdritaSharma updated, hope this helps

Comment: Please comment your image-cropper and see again, But it is not solution

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan I know, but when I extract `cropper.js` and include it without `ng-bootstrap` it would work fine

Comment: I think the ng-bootstrap module uses wrong `mousemove` event, can you use another module instead of ng-bootstrap or doesn't use the  `ngb-tabset` `ngb-tab`?

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan I was trying to use normal `bootstrap4`(tabs), but it turned out, when I add data dynamically, it does not render properly the content of it's tabs. I use this https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/examples .

Comment: are you connect the jquery on your code when you use bootsrap 4?

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan Here(https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) it's written, that I shouldn't include bootstrap, but I tried it with bootstrap(js) and without